# Getting a SIGABRT error in dismissModalViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

Im receiving a `SIGABRT` error when I cancel a `MFMailComposeViewController`, exactly in the `dismissViewController`, don't work

I have a `UIViewController` within a `UINavigationController`.

My Code:

```
- (void)sendMail {
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
        controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        [[controller navigationBar] setTintColor:[UIColor getHexColorWithRGB:@"e2de09" alpha:1.0f]];
        controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [controller setSubject:@"Subject"];            

        NSString *msg="xxxxx";
        [controller setMessageBody:msg isHTML:YES];

        [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];

    } else {
        NSString * errorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"mail account not set."];

        UIAlertView * errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error:" message:errorString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [errorAlert show];
    }
}
```

The `presentModalViewController:animated:` works correctly.

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

But calling `[self dissmissModalViewControllerAnimatedLYES]` causes a `SIGABRT` error.

Comment: What appears in the log? There should text that says something about an exception, or maybe something else. Post it above please.

Comment: I have a NSZombieEnabled actived, in Console doesn't apperas nothing, the only log I can see:   0x9a8b7c50  <+0000>  mov    $0xc0025,%eax  
0x9a8b7c55  <+0005>  call     0x9a856dd8 <_sysenter_trap>  
0x9a8b7c5a  <+0010>  jae      0x9a8b7c6a <__kill+26> --> Program received signal: SIGABRT    
0x9a8b7c5c  <+0012>  call   0x9a8b7c61 <__kill+17>   
0x9a8b7c61  <+0017>  pop    %edx  
0x9a8b7c62  <+0018>  mov    0x6401c87(%edx),%edx  
0x9a8b7c68  <+0024>  jmp    *%edx  
0x9a8b7c6a  <+0026>  ret

Answer (score 1):

I think the "dismissModalViewControllerAnimated" should be called on the MFMailComposer object, in your case "controller". Note that it is in fact a view controller.

Comment: I have changeg by: [controller dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; and nothing.

Comment: In a NSlog I ask if object is a UIViewController: NSLog(@"%@",([[controller classForCoder] isSubclassOfClass:[UIViewController class]])? @"yes":@"no");  and result is yes

Answer (score 1):

It's resolved!

I had a `viewWillDisappear:` method where I was removing views...

This method was being called before of present the ModalView and my ViewController was over released on `dissmissModalViewController`.

I have changed this method.

Thanks